# WCF netTcpBinding - can't access Metadata

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to run my service with the WCF Test Client using netTcpBinding (service runs fine with basicHTTP). I am getting the following error

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://chatmesh/mex If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: net.tcp://chatmesh/mex    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://chatmesh/mex'.    No DNS entries exist for host chatmesh.    No such host is known

I don't see anything blatantly wrong that would cause the problem.  Below is my app.config.  Does anyone have any suggetions for me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<!--SERVICE App.config file-->
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web> 
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MachineLibrary.Machine1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
          name="" contract="MachineLibrary.IMachine1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://Chatmesh" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```